# Appending text by column to the same row for a CSV file on Ruby 2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a CSV file that contains headers and 1 row of data:

I want to append data by the column name (the header) but to the same row (row number 1)

I'm inserting each column data separately.

So at the end, I will have a file that contains headers and 1 row of data

for example:

```
header1,header2

data1,data2
```

I'm using

```
 def insert_info_csv(header,values)
  headers=['1', '2', '3', '4']
  file='report_test.csv'

  CSV.open('report_test.csv','a') do |csv|
    row=CSV::Row.new(headers,[])
    row[header]=values (where I insert the data)
    csv << row
  end
  end
```

my issue is that each data is written in a different row for example:

```
 Header1, header2

 data1,

       ,data2
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you provide code where you actually write data to the final file?

Comment: Are you iterating somehow through the headers?

Comment: I've included the entire function in my post.

Comment: Not iterating through the headers.

Comment: You need to cycle through the `headers` and set up the value for each row you want to insert

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example it is clear that you are appending a row to the csv file per method call.
If you want to append data to existing row (by header) you need to add some identifier and fetch by it.
You could add entire row per method call by passing a hash to it.

```
hash = {
  header_a: 'value_a',
  header_b: 'value_b' 
}  

def insert_info_csv(info_hash)
 headers=['header_a', 'header_b']
 file='report_test.csv'

 CSV.open('report_test.csv','a') do |csv|
   row=CSV::Row.new(headers,[])
   info_headers.each do |k,v|
     row[k] = v
     csv << row
   end
 end
end
```